# Is it possible to set adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory globally?

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm working on a React Native app and I would like to set adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory=true globally for all elements present within app (UITextFieldLabel, RCTUITextField, etc). Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: Even if it's not possible to set it globally, how can I set it for a specific type of element that I have (e.g. UITextFieldLabel) ? I'm not experienced with Swift.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.